# Cancel Pipe execution in chain of observable rxjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs

In the below code, a chain of Observables are piped together. How to cancel the consequent pipe from being executed when the `parentObs1` throws an error ?

```
import { throwError } from "rxjs";
import { mergeMap, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
const parentObs1 = throwError("parentObs1");
const childObs2 = throwError("childObs2");
const grandChildObs3 = throwError("grandChildObs3");
parentObs1
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(() => childObs2),
    catchError((error) => throwError("Error in Obs1 CatchError block"))
  )
  // how to skip this pipe if the previous pipe throws error
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(() => grandChildObs3),
    catchError((error) => throwError("Error in Obs2 CatchError block"))
  )
  .subscribe(
    () => {},
    (error: any) => {
      console.log(error); // expect to print 'Error in Obs1 CatchError block' but prints 'Error in Obs2 CatchError block'
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `catchError` catches the first error and then throws a new error so you only see the second error message in your subscription.

I don't think you need the `catchError` operators at all:

```
parentObs1
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(() => childObs2),
    mergeMap(() => grandChildObs3),
  )
  .subscribe(
    () => {},
    (error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

Your errors will go straight to your subscription.

Comment: thanks. That was silly mistake to add the `catchError` inside the pipe.